# Runtime Error: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation:

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation

I have the following code for a reinforcement learning using proximal policy optimization. It gives the following run time error.

```
File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\RL\agent.py", line 91, in update_policy
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py", line 492, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 251, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [128, 4096]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

The code is

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

# Define the neural network for the policy
class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(PolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input_size, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return torch.softmax(x, dim=-1)

# Define the Proximal Policy Optimization agent
class PPOAgent:
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, lr=1e-3, gamma=0.99, epsilon=0.2, value_coef=0.5, entropy_coef=0.01):
        self.policy = PolicyNetwork(input_size, output_size)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.policy.parameters(), lr=lr)
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.value_coef = value_coef
        self.entropy_coef = entropy_coef

    def select_action(self, state):
        #print("state: ", state)
        xstate = torch.from_numpy(state).float()
        probs = self.policy(xstate)
        m = Categorical(probs)
        action = m.sample()
        return action.item(), m.log_prob(action)

    def update_policy(self, states, actions, rewards, log_probs, values, next_values, dones):
        torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
        returns = self.compute_returns(rewards, dones)
        """
        print("values", values, "next_values", next_values)
        print("size of values", len(values[0]), "size of next_values", len(next_values))
        print("type:",type(values[0]), type(values))
        print("returns", returns)
        print("size of returns", len(returns))
        print("type:", type(returns))
"""
        #convert values to tensor
        values = torch.tensor(values).float()
        advantages = returns - values
        print("advantages: ", advantages)
        

        for _ in range(ppo_epochs):
            for i in range(len(states)):
                state = torch.from_numpy(states[i]).float()
                action = torch.tensor(actions[i])
                old_log_prob = log_probs[i]
                value = values[i]
                next_value = next_values[i]
                advantage = advantages[i]
                return_ = returns[i]

                # Compute the new log probability and value
                new_probs = self.policy(state)
                new_log_prob = torch.log(new_probs[action])
                new_value = self.get_value(states[i])

                # Compute the surrogate loss
                ratio = torch.exp(new_log_prob - old_log_prob)
                surr1 = ratio * advantage
                surr2 = torch.clamp(ratio, 1 - self.epsilon, 1 + self.epsilon) * advantage
                policy_loss = -torch.min(surr1, surr2).mean()

                # Compute the value loss
                value_loss = F.mse_loss(new_value, return_)

                

                # Compute the entropy loss
                entropy_loss = -torch.sum(new_probs * torch.log(new_probs + 1e-10))

                # Total loss
                loss = policy_loss + self.value_coef * value_loss - self.entropy_coef * entropy_loss

                # Optimize the policy
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                print("loss: ", loss)
                with torch.autograd.detect_anomaly():
                    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
                self.optimizer.step()

    def compute_returns(self, rewards, dones):
        returns = []
        R = 0

        for reward, done in zip(reversed(rewards), reversed(dones)):
            if done:
                R = 0
            R = reward + self.gamma * R
            returns.insert(0, R)

        returns = torch.tensor(returns).float()
        returns = (returns - returns.mean()) / (returns.std() + 1e-8)

        return returns

    def get_value(self, state):
        print("ggstate: ", state)
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float()
        return self.policy(state)

# Set your environment parameters
input_size = 64  # Assuming a flat representation of the chess board as input
output_size = 64*64 # Number of legal moves in your chess environment

# Initialize the PPO agent
agent = PPOAgent(input_size, output_size)

# Training loop
num_episodes = 100
ppo_epochs = 4
"""
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    state = 0
    done = False

    states, actions, rewards, log_probs, values, next_values, dones = [], [], [], [], [], [], []

    while not done:
        action, log_prob = agent.select_action(state)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

        states.append(state)
        actions.append(action)
        rewards.append(reward)
        log_probs.append(log_prob)
        values.append(agent.get_value(state))
        next_values.append(agent.get_value(next_state))
        dones.append(done)

        state = next_state

    agent.update_policy(states, actions, rewards, log_probs, values, next_values, dones)
"""
```

I recently added "retain_graph=True" as parameter to backward function. Also I added torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True) but still gives the error.